# C getting equal hash values for different strings openssl

Tags: c, openssl, md5

i am pretty new to c. I am trying to compare two files with md5. 
I wrote a function which should return the hash values. But when comparing the values of different files or buffers, it says that they have the same hash.

```
unsigned char* getMD5(void *buffer, size_t bsize) {
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;
    const EVP_MD *md;
    unsigned char hashwert[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    int hashwert_laenge;
    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
    md = EVP_get_digestbyname("MD5");
    mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, buffer, bsize);
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, hashwert, &hashwert_laenge);
    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
    return hashwert;
}

//in main...
char mess[] = "abc";
cahr mess2[] = "bcd";
if(strcmp(getMD5(mess, strlen(mess)),getMD5(mess2, strlen(mess2))==0) {
   printf("euqal\n");
}else {
   printf("not equal \n"); 
}
```

I always get that the buffers are equal, even if they are not.
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compile with all warnings enabled and debugging info, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux.

It will have warned you: *function returns address of local variable*.

<sup>Newbies and expert C programmers usually should improve their code till no warnings are given. If your code triggers a warning that you really cannot avoid you should at least comment very carefully why.</sup>

You cannot meaningfully return the address of some local array.

You could `return strdup(hashwert);` and have the convention that the calling function (the caller) should `free` the result.

Or you could have a different API, for example having `hashwert` be a parameter of your function.

Comment: Yes there was a warning, i fixed it with using an additional buffer as parameter, instead of returning. thx!